# JSF configuration problem

Tags: jsf

I am trying to configure JSF with the help of this blog http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/01/jsf-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-tomcat.html

I cant see preferences-> web -> JSF Tools -> libraries
I need to include mojjaira but i didnt see library option here
help me where can i see this option

Comment: In eclipse? little more context needed..

Comment: What is “mojjaira“? Do you mean Mojarra?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using Eclipse 3.6. That tutorial was targeted on Eclipse 3.5 and the location of that preference has been changed in Eclipse 3.6. It's now available by a generic preference: *Java > Build Path > User Libraries*. But you can also just skip the step altogether and specify it during the *Dynamic Web Project* wizard. Or even better, head to the [JSF 2.0 tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html), it's targeted on Eclipse 3.6.

Answer (score -1):

Just include [JK-Faces](https://github.com/kiswanij/jk-faces) maven dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jalalkiswani</groupId>
        <artifactId>jk-faces</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9-1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

, and it will configure everything for you. Give it a try